# can some provide simple example of socket.io with socket.io/redis-stream-adapter for producer and consumer Nodejs?

Tags: socket.io, redis-streams

I want to simple example of socket.io and socket.io/redis-stream-adaper in which where **one server should add data to redis stream** and **another server should read that from redis-stream** and **send it client**. How to do it?

I have tried creating server(consumer) using socker.io/redis-stream-adapter documentation and
try adding to redis-stream using 'xadd' method but i dont want to using xadd method. I there any way adding ton redis stream using socker.io/redis-stream-adapter?